# Does Notepad++ / NppFTP supports Pageant and how to configure the profile?

Tags: windows, notepad++, plugins

Currently I use Pageant to provide SSH private key encrypted with passphrase.

Once the Pageant is started, passphrase is entered and for apps like Putty no passphrase is needed to be entered until the system is rebooted.

Is is possible to setup an profile for NppFTP plugin so the credentials from Pageant are used without need to reenter the passphrase?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is currently limitation of Notepad++, source: https://github.com/ashkulz/NppFTP/issues/181